# How to make my side bar to look dynamic when page zoom is growing?

Tags: html, vue.js, frontend, vue-component, vuetify.js

Code in "style" segment needs to be changed in that way that when I zoom browser to more than 100% or page is not opened on whole screen, i want to see only icons of side nav. This picture is random but shows exactly what I am looking for (https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsEES.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsEES.png)`
What should I do?

Comment: zooming is different from changing browser size. are you sure you don't mean changing browser size? media query is probably what you want.

Comment: Yup media query is thing that i should go with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just implement media query and that's it.... very simple